# Image as tool tip in combo box item for windows form application using C#

Tags: c#

I want to show image as a tool tip on each item in combo box on mousehover using C# in windows form. I tried to find event which may occur when mouse hover to it so that I can show a picture box near to it, but there is no such event.
Each item have respected image.

Comment: There is no direct way. You can workaround by setting a timer and checking the position. While it is inside the dropdown you can show the image.. when no longer inside you close the dropdown & the image  and stop the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of event doesn't exist for `ComboBox`. You will have to create it yourself.

Don't worry ! someone has done it for you.

Have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14255/ComboBox-firing-events-when-hovering-on-the-dropdo) nice and detailed article for creating a `Hover` event of `ComboBox`.

It is a bit complicated. But there is no other way around.